# Do I have to use Disable/EnableControls when using Locate in a TClientDataSet?

Tags: delphi

Or does it handle it by default?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Locate doesn't disable controls by default, no. Whether or not you *need* to do so depends upon whether you have visual controls connected.

Answer (score 1):

Locate **does not** call *DisableControls / EnableControls* on the *TClientDataSet*, but it may not always provide an obvious benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, before you fire your locate, one would disable controls and then right after the result, enable controls. As mentioned above it is not automatic and the only reason to do this would be to save some time during your search, query other database action by disabling visual controls that take time to repaint and/or refresh.

Benefits in time... depends on your program. Other than that, I see no real reason to do this.

John